# Get View Not binding all the child elements

Tags: android

I am using a `Gallery` and I bind a `ImageView`, `ImageButton` and a `ProcessBar` to it. There are more than 50 images in the gallery and in the `getView()` method when took the `ViewGroup.getChildCount()`. It returns only an int value of 3.

Why the `ViewGroup.getChildCount()` returns 3 even if I scroll all the images are there.

So I am getting error in the method :

```
ViewGroup.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Main Activity

```
public class SliderActivity extends Activity {  

     private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                R.drawable.sample_1,
                R.drawable.sample_2,
                R.drawable.sample_3,
                R.drawable.sample_4,
                R.drawable.sample_5,
                R.drawable.sample_6,
                R.drawable.sample_7
        };
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);               

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mImageIds));      

    }


}
```

ImageAdapter Class :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Activity mContext;
    private Integer[] Images;
    private int[] ID;
    private ProgressBar process;
    private ImageButton imgBtn;
    private ImageView imageview;


    public ImageAdapter(Activity c,Integer[] images) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.Images=images;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGal999lery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGal999lery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();

        ID=new int[getCount()];
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Images.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 1;
    }



    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {  


         View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView==null)
        {

         LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null, true);

         imageview=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewuser);    
         imgBtn=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.Download);
         process=(ProgressBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);

         imageview.setImageResource(Images[position]);               
         imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
         imageview.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);        


         if(position==0)
         {
             if(ID[position]==1)
             {
                 imgBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 process.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }          
         }

         if(ID[position]==position && position!=0)
         {
             imgBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             process.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }               
        }                                                    
        else{
            Log.e("Else", "Else case");     
        }

        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                if(position==0)
                {
                    ID[position]=1;                     
                }
                else
                {
                    ID[position]=position;
                }
                parent.getChildCount();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
                BackgroundAsyncTask objDownload=new BackgroundAsyncTask(parent,position);
                objDownload.execute();
            }

        }); 
         return rowView;                    
    }



    private class BackgroundAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

      public BackgroundAsyncTask(ViewGroup vg,int position) {       
            this.subGroup=vg;   
            this.pos=position;
        }

    int myProgress; 
    private ViewGroup subGroup;
    private int pos;

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          subGroup.getChildAt(pos).findViewById(R.id.Download).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
          subGroup.getChildAt(pos).findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);             
          Toast.makeText(mContext,"Download finished "+pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          ID[1]=0;

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub           
       myProgress = 0;
       imgBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       while(myProgress<100){
        myProgress++;
        publishProgress(myProgress);
           SystemClock.sleep(100);               
       }
    return null;              
}

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            process.setProgress(values[0]);

      }
     }      
}
```

Comment: and we are stuck without code :(

Comment: I have updated with ma code..Please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your `getView`

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {  


     View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView==null)
    {

     LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
     rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null, true);

     imageview=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewuser);    
     imgBtn=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.Download);
     process=(ProgressBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
     }

     imageview.setImageResource(Images[position]);               
     imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
     imageview.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);        


     if(position==0)
     {
         if(ID[position]==1)
         {
             imgBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             process.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }          
     }

     if(ID[position]==position && position!=0)
     {
         imgBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         process.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }               

    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            if(position==0)
            {
                ID[position]=1;                     
            }
            else
            {
                ID[position]=position;
            }
            parent.getChildCount();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
            BackgroundAsyncTask objDownload=new BackgroundAsyncTask(parent,position);
            objDownload.execute();
        }

    }); 
     return rowView;                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android optimizes this.
Say, you have a ListView and it have an infinity number of elements. 
If you query child count of it, it will return for example 10 childs. Its happens because android creating only views which currently on screen and them just reuses them.

You can read more in doc about [Adapter.getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29), check out second arg `convertView`.